# JQuery, specific date targeting not working as expected

Tags: jquery, html

I've already been helped getting this code to a point on stack overflow which is much appreciated as always and I have a 95% working script.

The bit thats not working and confusing me is there is a part that says only display a target div between these date ranges and these time ranges on them dates:

```js
// Message to appear before countdown
var countdownMessage = "Hurry ends in";

//Set time for countdown to count down till - 24 hour clock
var endHour = 20
var endMin = 59

//Set days to run from/until - 0 = sunday | 6 = saturday
var startDay = 0
var endDay = 5

//Set hours to run from/until - 0 = 12am-12:59am | 10 = 10am-10:59am | 12 = 12pm-12:59pm | 16 = 4pm-4:59pm | 23 = 11pm-11:59pm
var startTime = 6
var endTime = 21
    
    

//////////////////////////* Countdown *///////////////////////////////
$(document).ready(function(){
    function getSeconds() {
        var now = new Date();
        var time = now.getTime(); // time now in milliseconds
        var countdownEnd = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), (endHour),(endMin)); // countdownEnd 0000 hrs
        var ft = countdownEnd.getTime() + 86400000; // add one day
        var diff = ft - time;
        diff = parseInt(diff / 1000);
        if (diff > 86400) {
            diff = diff - 86400
        }
        startTimer(diff);
    }

    var timeInSecs;
    var ticker;

    function startTimer(secs) {
        timeInSecs = parseInt(secs);
        ticker = setInterval(tick, 1000);
        tick(); // to start counter display right away
    }

    function tick() {
        var secs = timeInSecs;
        if (secs > 0) {
            timeInSecs--;
        } else {
            clearInterval(ticker); // stop counting at zero
            //getSeconds();  // and start again if required
        }

        var hours = Math.floor(secs / 3600);
        secs %= 3600;
        var mins = Math.floor(secs / 60);
        secs %= 60;
        var result = ((hours < 10) ? "0" : "") + hours + " hours " + ((mins < 10) ? "0" : "") + mins + " minutes " + ((secs < 10) ? "0" : "") + secs + " seconds";
        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = (countdownMessage) + " " + result; 
    }

    $("#countdown").hide();

    ///////////////* Display at certain time of the day *//////////////////

    //gets the current time. 
    var d = new Date();
    var day = d.getDay();

    if (day >= (startDay) && day <= (endDay)) {
        if (d.getHours() >= (startTime) && d.getHours() <= (endTime)) {
            $("#countdown").show();
        }
    }

    getSeconds();
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="countdown" style="font-weight: bold;">&nbsp;</span>
```

Although the time ranges work fine the date part is acting unusual, in the above code it's set to show all the way from sunday(**0**) till saturday(**6**) so it should always be showing, but it's not however if you change the date range to tuesday(**2**) till saturday(**6**) it works fine (today is tuesday at the time of posting).

Can anyone help explain whats going on and whats wrong?

Thanks

Comment: First of all, why the damn are you even trying to show countdown "only" if current day is sunday, monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday or saturday??? Basically today == a week day, `if` should be always true. What is the alternative, a black hole in time?

Comment: Actually on the site I intend to have 2 of these setup, 1 with a message on Sun - Monday, then a different message on Saturday. I just  made it Sun - Sat in the example so you could see it should show no matter what day you try the code but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be checking if it is the start day or if it is the end day, but not checking if it's between the start day and end day.  So if it's a day between then you aren't showing the countdown, if I'm hearing your complaint properly.  (So you might have had this working for value 2 if the current day actually was value 2, or etc.)

```
if (day == (startDay) || day == (endDay)) {
```

perhaps should be:

```
if (day >= (startDay) && day <= (endDay)) {
```

Comment: Sigh, it was that simple that I'd overlooked. Thank you Bounty awarded.